# composer warning : the version constraint has no upper bound

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have under my [composer.json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ahmed-bhs/178eecd029d757dcbf7cd560fa20484c/raw/5373cc93b19ac019d3902ce6544e147e134f7294/composer.json) this list of packages:

```
    "symfony/asset": "*",
    "symfony/console": "*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1", // ther's no warning here
    "symfony/form": "*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/translation": "*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "*",
    "symfony/validator": "*",
    "symfony/web-link": "*",
    "symfony/yaml": "*",
```

Unfortunately, after trying validating composer dependencies via `composer validate`  I'm getting this warning:

> Unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided.
>
> The version constraint has no upper bound - this is not a good idea.

I found the raison why under the officiel doc https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-are-unbound-version-constraints-a-bad-idea.md But I have no idea how to fix the warrning.

Any idea how to update automatically (else manually) the `"*"` to the current installed version, via just some useful `composer` command lines. 
(To define an upper bound on my constraints).

Comment: This is a terrible idea to require `*` in the first place.

Comment: @emix, thak you interraction, I think it's the composer behavior after installing dependencies. Any idea how Fix this

Comment: Forgot it's restricted internally. You can ignore this warning as this is not an error.

Comment: This might be solved for newer projects with Flex 1.1: https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/421

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea how to update automatically (else manually) the "*" to the current installed version, via just some useful composer command lines.

There is no composer command like `composer set-version symfony/* 4.2`

**You need to do this manually.**

How did "find and replace" `"*"` → `"^4.2"` in `*.json` files worked for you?

I assume you'd like to use the newest Symfony version - 4.2 at the time being. If you'd like to use the installed one, just run: `composer show symfony/asset` to find the version.

Btw, don't worry. You have to do this only once a ~2 years :)

Comment: Thank you so mush for your answer, In fact I'm writing a travis ci script to validate the composer.json after every new intalled package.
So, wether I use `composer show symfony/asset` or copy directlly the version from `composer.lock` as it's already specified there ?
A question : as a good practice, are we supposed to validate the `composer.json` and the `composer.lock` or just the `composer.lock` is enough ?

Comment: In this case, 1) delete `composer.lock`, 2) then change the version in `composer.json` to 4.2, 3) then run `composer install`. That way you'll have valid versions in both `composer.*` files.

Comment: 1)I can just run `composer update --lock`. In general is it a good practice to validate both of the files ? because I think every time i install a new package and the package is tagged with `"*"`...In that case, I'm obliged to redefine the exact version.
I'm thinking about an option like `--no-check-all` to skip `.json file validation` ...Is is a good or bad idea ?

Comment: Use only `composer.json`. The `composer.lock` is for the internal needs of composer, not for you. Everytime you install a new package, composer picks the highest version itself: `composer require package/name`. I have no idea how did you get `*` version if not manually :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the `extra` section from your `composer.json` that defines which Symfony version to use for dependencies. They changed it for 4.x to not have every package use a version constraint so it's easier to update the whole framework to another version, but at the same time keeping all Symfony components on the same version.

Try adding this to the `composer.json` file and running `composer update`:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "require": "^4.2"
    }
}
```

Edit: Sorry, overlooked that you're using `composer validate`. Apparently this doesn't take into account the `extra` definition which is really only a hint for the Flex Composer plugin so it's not recognized by Composer itself.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I already have that extra section. But that section is introducted from whish version ?

Comment: It's a Flex feature. It works for `update`, but apparently not for `validate`. You don't need to set the exact version of the framework you're using, just use a sensible version constraint. Or copy the one that's defined in the "extra" section. If it's `4.1.*`, just replace all the asterisks (the unbounded constraints) with that and you'll be fine. If you want Symfony 4.2, use `4.2.*` or `^4.2`.

Comment: I didnt understand ...In fact I have only symfony version under `extra`, the other's are under ``require` So, to fix it we need to replace all  the asterisks under `composer.json`. take a look https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ahmed-bhs/178eecd029d757dcbf7cd560fa20484c/raw/5373cc93b19ac019d3902ce6544e147e134f7294/composer.json

Comment: Yes. Replace all the `"*"` for packages starting with `symfony/` with `"4.2.*"`. You'll lose the ability to change the version by only editing one line, but `composer validate` will not fail again.

Comment: It's like Tomas solution, so. thank you anyway :) Could at least reforme you answer to vote for it.

Comment: Thank you so mush for you help, really appreciate ^^

Answer (score -1):

You may use following command to update it to the latest versions

```
composer update
```

But would recommend to have a version specific packages instead of "*", so as to avoid conflict with the future packages

Comment: composer upadate will not solve the problème. Thank you for your try :)